# Laravel Dual Auth Mechanism: Database and REST API

Tags: php, rest, laravel, authentication

I have to set up an authentication system on Laravel 5.1.19 that will handle two types of users: CMS admin users and regular end users:

- The CMS admin credentials will be mapped in Laravel's database so i
  can use the default Laravel auth mechanism (Eloquent model & all)
- The regular users will be stored on a different db that won't be
  directly accessible. The credential checking for regulars is
  implemented via a REST call to a dedicated server that can query that
  db.

Admins and regulars will have different login pages. My questions are:

### How can I have two auth mechanisms mapped to two separate routes?

Say /login/admin is the login URL for CMS admins. This request should be handled by the default auth.
Say /login/users is the login URL for regulars. This should be handled by a custom auth that will issue REST requests to a different server for credential checking and retrieval of other necessary user info.

### How can I implement a custom auth mechanism that doesn't store any info in Laravel's db?

Making REST calls should be easy. My problem is that all auth tutorials assume that the user will be mapped in a db table and my requirements make it impossible to do so. I read a post on laravel.io where somebody said that he tried to save the User object in Session but he didn't get into much detail.

---

### Update: A Preliminary Solution

Following [this laravel.io post](http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5) I managed to create a custom `UserProvider` class that extends `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` that is overriding the `retrieveById($identifier)` method such that it first tries to retrieve the user object from the `Session`. If nothing's found then it delegates the operation to its parent, `EloquentUserProvider`:

```
class CustomUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider {
  public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model)
  {
      parent::__construct($hasher, $model);
  }

  public function retrieveById($identifier)
  {
    $user = getSessionUser($identifier);

    if ($user) {
      return $user;
    } else {
      return parent::retrieveById($identifier);
    }
  }
...
```

Other than this, I just stored the current user in `Session` in my `LoginController`.
The setup of a custom `UserProvider` is documented in the above-mentioned post.

Hope this helps someone and if you guys have something to add, please do.
Thanks!

Comment: You can keep the user information in a cookie which you encrypt. If cookie is provided, if decryption succeeds and if information in there makes sense (your app is able to find required keys or whatever) then that's it.

Comment: @Mjh Thanks! This is a way of filtering requests, right? My problem with this approach is having to invoke the REST API each time I have to check the cookie. I want to do the credential checking REST call only at _login_ and then store the user info in Session (not DB) and (if possible) rely on Laravel's authorization mechanism

Comment: Then you perform the authentication (initially) and you set up middleware. Middleware checks whether the cookie is valid (if it exists, if it's decryptable and if information in it makes sense). Then you just put your routes behind that middleware. Unless the middleware check passes, the route will be inaccessible. I think it was called route filters prior to laravel 5.0 but I'm not sure. That way you don't have to invoke anything. You just place routes behind middleware.

Comment: This Middleware feature sounds promising. I'll keep that as an option but for now I'd like to keep away from using cookies.